# about android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I find a question that when my program killed by some process manager,the broadcast can't received,why?
But the alarm clock will work even when it was killed.How to realize this function like the alarm work,I'm wrting an app of Crontab.
Any help is thanksgiving!

Comment: are you registering broadcast in `Activity` or in `Manifest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process is being killed, so all the resources, threads associated with your process is going to be removed or already removed. Then how can your receiver can receive the  notifications?